# Python numpy Attribute Error '_collapse'

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas, attributeerror

I am getting the strangest Attribute error in python, and I can't seem to find anything about it online. 
I am trying to sum the elements of all columns of a matrix y, and save those in a new matrix. y is a 1063 x 1063 identity matrix of 1.'s and 0.'s.
mat is a 70000 x 1063 sparse matrix

```
mat = scipy.sparse.rand(70000, 1063, density=0.01, format='coo', dtype=None, random_state=None)
mat.shape
```

gives me:

```
(70000, 1063)
```

now i create y, a 1063 x 1063 identity matrix:

```
y = np.matlib.identity(1063)  
ind = np.nonzero((mat.sum(axis=0) < 20))
y[ind, :] = 0                 # replace element at given index with 0 

x = np.sum(y, axis=1)         # here i want to count the elements of all columns of y
```

I am getting the following error regarding the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_collapse'
```

I am lost. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: What type of data are you passing in the ndarray, `y`?

Comment: y is a matrix of floats

Comment: What does `type(y)` give?

Comment: Oh, it gives: numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

Comment: And which shape? `y.shape` Better provide a minimal non-working example. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It would help if you showed how `y` was created.  Can you add a minimal (but runnable) example that generates `y`?

Comment: My bad, I am somewhat new to this. I just edited my question, it should be more clear now. Feel free to ask for whichever further information you need. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: What are `mat` and `ind`?  If you can, please show enough code for us to copy and run ourselves.  By the way, the first argument of `np.matrixlib.identity` is expected to be an integer.  If I try to pass in a nontrivial matrix (i.e. with shape other than (1,1)), I get an error.

Comment: (I meant `np.matlib.identity` in my previous comment.)

Comment: Thank you Warren, I edited my question once more. The argument in    np.matlib.identity should be an integer, I made a mistake copying my code in here. The identity matrix should be 1063 by 1063 of course! Sorry about that. I also cleared up what mat and ind are doing.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with the given information. A complete example is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but without `Users/me/Desktop/mat.csv`, we *still* can't run the same code you are running.  Can you reproduce the problem by creating a different `mat` that doesn't depend on your csv file?  E.g. `mat = pd.DataFrame(...put some explicit, self-contained data here...)`

Comment: I'm so sorry, this must be frustrating for you guys! Let mat be a random sparse matrix with the shape 70000 x 1063! Re-edited my question again

Comment: Thanks.  Now the problem is your code works fine for me. :)  I'm using numpy 1.9.1 and scipy 0.14.0.  Which versions of numpy and scipy are you using?

Comment: Interesting, I am using numpy 1.9.0, scipy 0.14.0, and pd 0.14.1. That must be the issue! Do you know how I can update that?

Comment: Depends on how you installed Numpy. Please consult your python/Numpy distribution and your favorite search engine.

Comment: I did an update, and I got numpy version: '1.10.0.dev+c39a56a' - and I still get the same error. I am using Anaconda IPython Notebook and it can not seem to find a version 1.9.1

Comment: Your code runs fine on numpy 1.8.2

Comment: Works for me on numpy 1.8.1 and scipy 0.14.0 too

Answer (score 4):

In `matrixlib/defmtrix.py` `_collapse` is defined as a method of class `Matrix`:

```
def _collapse(self, axis):
    """A convenience function for operations that want to collapse
    to a scalar like _align, but are using keepdims=True
    """
    if axis is None:
        return self[0, 0]
    else:
        return self
```

`_collapse` is being used in:

```
def sum(self, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None):
    return N.ndarray.sum(self, axis, dtype, out, keepdims=True)._collapse(axis)
```

It is also used like this in methods like `.mean`, `.prod`, `.any`, `.max`.  Basically any operation that normally would reduce a dimension of the matrix.

Normally these operations return an array of the same type as the input, so if `y` is a matrix, it should return a matrix.  And since a matrix is always 2d, `keepdims=True` is used.  `._collapse` is needed in the case where the operation reduces the matrix to a scalar (e.g. axis is None).  Then we want a true scalar, not one wrapped in a matrix.

I doubt if this part of the code has changed in years (I'll double check on github).

---

So it's defined for a `matrix`, but not a `ndarray`.

```
In [154]: np.matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])._collapse(0)
Out[154]: 
matrix([[1, 0],
        [0, 1]])

In [155]: np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])._collapse(0)
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_collapse'
```

It appears as though the `np.sum` is not returning a `matrix` even though the input is one.

---

I wonder if the other reduction functions have the same problem, for example

```
y.max(axis=0)
np.add.reduce(y, axis=0)
```

---

`y.max`, `y.prod`, etc are all coded the same as `y.sum`.  For a `matrix` this means using the underlying `ndarray` function followed by `._collapse`.

`np.add.reduce(y, axis=1, keepdims=True)` is functionally quite similar, though the route to the underlying C code is different.  And it does not attempt to call `._collapse`, which means that for `axis=None` it does not reduce the result to a scalar; it is left a `(1,1)` matrix.  `._collapse` could still be used, as in:

```
np.add.reduce(np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6'),axis=None, keepdims=True)._collapse(None)
# 21
```

Another option around a problem with `np.sum` is to convert `y` to an array (and optionally back to `matrix`):

```
np.matrix(np.sum(y.A, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

`sparse` takes another route to `.sum` - multiply the matrix with a matrix of 1s:

```
y * np.asmatrix(np.ones((y.shape[1],1),int))
```

I wonder if your problems are being caused by some other module that you are importing, one that is overwriting some definition, say of type `matrix`.  You have a `pandas` tag.  Does that mean you load `pandas` as part of this calculation?  I'm not blaming `pandas`, but it suggests that the program environment is more complicated.  Try the calculations with the simplest program possible.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried x = y.sum(axis=1) and got the same error again. So you are saying it could be because y is a matrix and I try an ndarray operation on it?

Comment: If `y` was array, then the `matrix` version of `sum` would not be called, and there'd be no attempt to call `._collapse`. How does `np.matrix([]).sum(0)` behave?

Comment: Does `np.prod(y, axis=1)` give the same error? (or any of the other 'reduction' methods)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I tried all those out, and it worked for `np.add.reduce(y, axis=0)` - however, it gave me the same error with `_collapse` for `y.max(axis=0)` as well as `np.prod(y, axis=1)`. I can not explain it. Is there any possible other way to sum through the columns of a matrix?

Comment: `np.add.reduce(y, axis=1)`?  I've added some more thoughts on using `add.reduce` and alternatives.